# Use Sitefinity MVC model set to set input type attribute

Tags: c#, sitefinity

Trying to change the "type" attribute of one of my form fields - specifically from "text" to "tel". I did not set this up initially - I was handed an existing site with minimal documentation.

I see in the `Write.Default.cshtml` file that the `type` attribute maps to `@Model.InputType.ToHtmlInputType`.

I also see in my FormModel.cs a that the `Telephone` var is defined:

```
[Display(Name = "Telephone number")]
[Phone(ErrorMessage = "Telephone number is not valid")]
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Telephone number is required")]
public string Telephone { get; set; }
```

However I haven't the slightest clue how bridge that gap. I tried setting various properties here but they always resulted in a build error.

Comment: Write.Default.cshtml is when you use the Forms Builder in Sitefinity, in which case you do not need a FormModel.cs class.
So you probably have a custom form with a custom View, so you may want to check that

Comment: Check the controller for the widget than look for the accompanying view. I.e. MyTestController should have a folder MVC/Views/MyTest and in there you'll possibly have index.cshtml?

Comment: Is this widget being used in the form builder or on a page? As mentioned the example you gave would apply to a form builder widget not a page widget.